# How can I fix front-end code in django-models. I want to transfer model's informations from admin site to HTML code.Namely models destroying my code

Tags: python, html, django-models, frontend, django-admin

in my program when I added informations to specific model.But It breaking my HTML code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtu3Y.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l677c.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efmzs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsJcL.png)

I added informations . it should represent in a row instead of incorrect positions

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.